# R NaiveBayes issue with numeric variables

Tags: r, numeric, naivebayes

Even though the NaiveBayes() help says that numeric can be passed in the first parameter 'x', I am not able to run it successfully. Without numeric variable(resale) it works fine. Here is the script:

```
    library(readr)
    library(klaR)
    ### load dataset
    Dataset <- read_csv("D:/sampledata.csv")
    ### converting 'model' and 'type' to factor
    Dataset$model <- factor(Dataset$model)
    Dataset$type <- factor(Dataset$type)
    ### Executing NaiveBayes with numeric 'resale'
    NaiveBayesModel1 <- NaiveBayes(model~type+mylogical+resale,data=Dataset,na.action =na.omit)
    ### now removing resale. Following works as expected.
    NaiveBayesModel1 <- NaiveBayes(model~type+mylogical,data=Dataset,na.action =na.omit)
```

'model' and 'type' are factors,
'mylogical' is a logical and
'resale' is a numeric variable.
Since, I cannot attach my datafile, I am pasting few rows here. Copy these rows and save as sampledata.csv file on your drive. Modify read_csv() in the above script to point to this csv file.

```
"model","sales","resale","type","mylogical"
"Integra",16.919,16.36,"Automobile",TRUE
"TL",39.384,19.875,"Automobile",FALSE
"Camry",247.994,13.245,"Automobile",FALSE
"Avalon",63.849,18.14,"Automobile",TRUE
"Celica",33.269,15.445,"Automobile",TRUE
"Tacoma",84.087,9.575,"Truck",TRUE
"RAV4",25.106,13.325,"Truck",FALSE
"4Runner",68.411,19.425,"Truck",FALSE
"Land Cruiser",9.835,34.08,"Truck",TRUE
"Golf",9.761,11.425,"Automobile",FALSE
"Jetta",83.721,13.24,"Automobile",FALSE
"Passat",51.102,16.725,"Automobile",TRUE
"Cabrio",9.569,16.575,"Automobile",FALSE
"GTI",5.596,13.76,"Automobile",FALSE
```

I get following error if I run NaiveBayes with "resale".

```
Error in if (any(temp)) stop("Zero variances for at least one class in variables: ",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

R help ( help(NaiveBayes) ) says I can use numeric. I don't understand what is wrong. Please help.

Regards,
SG

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by zero variance in variable `resale` values for each of the outcomes in `model`. Most likely your training set contains single training record for each distinct value in `model`.

Comment: I see the problem now. Each model have frequency 1. I tested with different data and it worked. Thanks for the help.